# why .mod files differ after every time i compile a .f file

Tags: compiler-construction, module, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a fortran file say abc.f.

This abc.f has some code inside and defines a module say abcd.

When i compile the file using ifort compiler it creates abcd.mod,and abc.o.

I save these .o and .mod file in another location and recompile the abc.f.

Now when i compare the new abcd.mod with old one it differs, but .o files are same.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Fwiw, gfortran used to store a timestamp in its module files as well, but that feature has since been removed since it caused problems for users interested in reproducible builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a timestamp which is included in the `mod` files.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp you can refer this for more on timestamp

Answer (score 2):

probably timestamping. Try running `strings` on the `.mod` and checking it - mostly likely the first few lines.

Comment: `strings` gives same result for both .mod

Comment: it's a timestamp, but it's the time in seconds since 1970 stored in binary, so strings will not work.

Comment: steabert, are you sure that its timestamp only.
Can you please give me some links(reference regarding your answer) where i can find the fact

Comment: I don't know if there's any public documentation on ifort .mod file specification. I inferred this from comparing two generated module files and only 4 bytes were different, and those 4 bytes are the time in seconds since 1970.

Comment: It is a timestamp. There is no public documentation on the format. The first 48 bytes are information on the target platform and version. The next four (IA-32) or eight (x64) bytes are the timestamp. If you filter those out, the contents should be the same from compile to compile. We did have an issue where unused bytes were not being zeroed, leading to other differences, but we fixed that a while ago.

Comment: With gfortran, there is also a timestamp in the first record

Comment: @FrancoisJacq: As I mentioned in another comment, current versions of gfortran do not include a timestamp in the .mod files.

Comment: After building the whole source code i got a lib.a, the same problem is here also occurs ie after rebuilding without making any changes lib.a differs.
@SteveLionel can you please explain the reason for this also.
Thanks for previous answer.

Comment: Object modules also have timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your answers.
Its a timestamp only which is making difference.
Timestamp is stored at 49 to 52 or 49 to 56 bytes(depending on architecture) in `.mod` file.
You can extract the remaining content using `dd` command for comparison.